# Runtime.getRuntime().exec is not working for JSP in MAC machine/mac book

Tags: java, shell, jsp

I am executing below commands from jsp(eg:shell.jsp) and I have set up for tomcat server.
and i am running in MAC machine/mac book.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*,java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.lang.Runtime" %>

String unixCommand = "sh /Users/admin/interface.sh";
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec(unixCommand);
```

I am getting below error

```
An error occurred at line: 9 in the jsp file: /file_upload_download/shell.jsp
**The method exec(String) is undefined for the type Runtime**
   String unixCommand = "sh /Users/admin/interface.sh";
      Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
```

Comment: Did you import the correct `Runtime` class?

Comment: I have imported java.lang.Runtime class but still not working in mac machine/mac book

Answer (score 0):

I have an application with common code on Windows/MAC. Below is how I use it:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(<your command>);
InputStream stderr = p.getErrorStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
System.out.println(line);
int exitCode = p.waitFor();
```

The stream reading helps to check the messages for the execution.

Comment: i have used Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls"); but still same problem..

Comment: Try calling p.waitFor(). Ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec()--> not working for me in mac and i have wasted 2 days. i found similar class and it was working for me.                         try{
   ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/Users/admin/interface.sh");
   Process process = probuilder.start();
   
            }catch (IOException e) {
                out.println(e.getMessage());
           }

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<%   
    try{
```

ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/Users/admin/interface.sh");

```
        Process process = probuilder.start();

        }catch (IOException e) {
            out.println(e.getMessage());
        }        
%>
</head>
<body>
```